# My new Sennheiser G4ME ZERO headset won't send audio to my Mac

Tags: audio, headphones, microphone

I recently purchases a Sennheiser G4ME Zero to replace my Steel Series Siberia V3. The Siberia's microphone worked just fine along with the audio. When I plugged my G4ME Zero in the audio output worked great. When I tested out the microphone, my Macbook didn't receive any input. I plugged in my old Siberia to see if it was a hardware problem with the Mac but it showed up as a working external mic.

I've tried switching out cords, blowing out the input, and just plugging in the microphone portion to the computer but it still won't work. Is it a hardware problem with the headset or what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a MacBook with a single 3.5mm jack, you need to make sure you are using the TRRS cable from Sennheiser. That's the one that will have 3 narrow bands on the shaft of the jack (separating the four metallic connections stereo/left, stereo/right, microphone, and ground). Is that how your Siberia works? Single cable?

Also be sure that the "boom arm" is not raised up as that will mute the microphone.